# ListBox not Selected the Correct Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a ListBox that display a list of description. The user is supposed to selected a description and do a post. It worked fine if the id is between 1 and 9. However, if the ID is 10 and above, it is getting confusing. For example, selected the 11th item (starting from 0), item 1 and 2 will be selected instead of the 11th item. 
What am doing wrong here?

Here is a sample of my model and listbox:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m =>m.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(Model.currValues, "ID", "Description", Model.SelectedValues), new { style = "width:98%; height:300px; clear:both; float:left; color: Inherit;", onchange = "ChangeIdentified();", id = "SelectedValues" })


public class CurrentUsers
{
  public string SelectedValues {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Values> currValues = new List<Values>
        {
            new Values { ID=0, Description=""}
        };

 [Serializable]
        public class Values
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

}
```

I have a web service that is returning an object of type CurrValue.

```
//calling it this way.
currValues = GetValueFromWebservice();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the line of code below. It worked perfectly after making the change.

```
public string SelectedValues {get;set;} 
to 
public List<int> SelectedValues {get;set;}
```